# Disabling an option in a dropdown menu - d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm relatively new to D3 and have been having a few issues getting started. I've created a dropdown menu using the code below

```
var signal = d3.select('#signal_container');
var signalName = ["Please Select", "Temperature", "Pressure"];
var signalSelect = signal
    .append('select')
    .attr('class', 'select')
    .attr('multiple', '');
var signalOptions = signalSelect
    .selectAll('option')
    .data(signalName).enter()
    .append('option')
    .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

I was wondering if there was a way for me to disable the 'Please Select' option so that the user can't select that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the property `disabled` to that option.

There are several ways for doing that. This one uses `each`:

```js
var signal = d3.select('body');
var signalName = ["Please Select", "Temperature", "Pressure"];
var signalSelect = signal
  .append('select')
  .attr('class', 'select')
  .attr('multiple', '');
var signalOptions = signalSelect
  .selectAll('option')
  .data(signalName)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .each(function(d) {
    if (d === "Please Select") {
      d3.select(this).property("disabled", true)
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to use the disabled property but wasn't sure how to do it for one option